# deactivate element (css) based on a JavaScript trigger

Tags: javascript, css

Based on the given selection i want to deaktivate the element(opt_hello_message_embed_color_title). Incase of the value NO the element should not be active. How can i realise that in javascript?

```
        <select id="opt_hello_message_embed" name="opt_embed">
          <option value="yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>

        <label for="embed_color_title">Embed color (if active)</label>
        <select id="opt_hello_message_embed_color_title" name="opt_embed_color_title">
          <option value="purple">Purple</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
          <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="black">Black</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: Listen to the `input` event on the first `<select>`. If value is `no`, then disable the second `<select>`.

Comment: Hi. Read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit you question to meet the requirements.

Comment: @AT-2017 have tried it with different things like onclick function but nothing worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the **disabled** property *true* to deactivate element

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#opt_hello_message_embed_color_title");
select.disabled = true;
```

```html
<select id="opt_hello_message_embed" name="opt_embed">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<label for="embed_color_title">Embed color (if active)</label>
<select id="opt_hello_message_embed_color_title" name="opt_embed_color_title">
  <option value="purple">Purple</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a addon to Ahsan's answer.

If you want the button dropdown to disappear use this:-

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#opt_hello_message_embed_color_title");
select.style.display= "none";// to make the dropdown reappear use select.style.display= "block";
```

```html
<select id="opt_hello_message_embed" name="opt_embed">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<label for="embed_color_title">Embed color (if active)</label>
<select id="opt_hello_message_embed_color_title" name="opt_embed_color_title">
  <option value="purple">Purple</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```